# How to check and list out or print the Observer which have been added into the Notification Center?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'd like to check and list out or print the Observer which have been added into the Notification Center.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(appplicationIsActive:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

Below is what I'd check, for example:

```
if(Observer in Notification Center ){

   .....

   .....

}else{

   .....

   .....

}
```

Comment: exists where? not sure what you mean. please elaborate your question in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no API to check if your observer in the NSNotificationCenter.
If you want to remove it, just call removeobserver function

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html